# Is it possible to show multiple jQuery Fancybox alerts on one page?

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to show multiple Fancybox alerts on one page i.e. A user triggers one alert, then within the alert, he can trigger another which will appear without closing the first.

Example
[Click the zoom icon on the products and then click the 'Tell a friend' link](http://www.freepeople.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/products.browse/categoryID/eb344a5e-2eb4-44f2-9bd1-39502a8fe6d1?categoryID=eb344a5e-2eb4-44f2-9bd1-39502a8fe6d1&categoryName=what%27s+new&corsetSize=loose&layoutType=none&showAll=0&startResult=1&overrideActionPersistence=true&refinementCount=1&hasLeftNav=YES&sortType=none&colorFilterSetOptionID=none&action=products.browse&sizes=st)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I would set up a java sciprt event with jQuery and whenever that event is fired, you do

$.fancybox({ 'content' : responseText });

You can do that as many times as you want on a page.